# Not able to install dependencies using conda

Tags: anaconda, conda, tensor, anaconda3

I'm trying to install dependencies for tensor flow development. For that I'm using a yml file `tfdl_env.yml`. Used the `conda env create`, so that it was supposed to install all the dependencies.

```
 conda env create -f tfdl_env.yml
```

But there it was shown that the `Solving environment: failed` and `RequiredPackageNotFound`. 
The `yml` files used is below.

```
name: tfdeeplearning
channels:
- defaults
dependencies:
- bleach=1.5.0=py35_0
- certifi=2016.2.28=py35_0
- colorama=0.3.9=py35_0
- cycler=0.10.0=py35_0
- decorator=4.1.2=py35_0
- entrypoints=0.2.3=py35_0
- html5lib=0.9999999=py35_0
- icu=57.1=vc14_0
- ipykernel=4.6.1=py35_0
- ipython=6.1.0=py35_0
- ipython_genutils=0.2.0=py35_0
- ipywidgets=6.0.0=py35_0
- jedi=0.10.2=py35_2
- jinja2=2.9.6=py35_0
- jpeg=9b=vc14_0
- jsonschema=2.6.0=py35_0
- jupyter=1.0.0=py35_3
- jupyter_client=5.1.0=py35_0
- jupyter_console=5.2.0=py35_0
- jupyter_core=4.3.0=py35_0
- libpng=1.6.30=vc14_1
- markupsafe=1.0=py35_0
- matplotlib=2.0.2=np113py35_0
- mistune=0.7.4=py35_0
- mkl=2017.0.3=0
- nbconvert=5.2.1=py35_0
- nbformat=4.4.0=py35_0
- notebook=5.0.0=py35_0
- numpy=1.13.1=py35_0
- openssl=1.0.2l=vc14_0
- pandas=0.20.3=py35_0
- pandocfilters=1.4.2=py35_0
- path.py=10.3.1=py35_0
- pickleshare=0.7.4=py35_0
- pip=9.0.1=py35_1
- prompt_toolkit=1.0.15=py35_0
- pygments=2.2.0=py35_0
- pyparsing=2.2.0=py35_0
- pyqt=5.6.0=py35_2
- python=3.5.4=0
- python-dateutil=2.6.1=py35_0
- pytz=2017.2=py35_0
- pyzmq=16.0.2=py35_0
- qt=5.6.2=vc14_6
- qtconsole=4.3.1=py35_0
- requests=2.14.2=py35_0
- scikit-learn=0.19.0=np113py35_0
- scipy=0.19.1=np113py35_0
- setuptools=36.4.0=py35_1
- simplegeneric=0.8.1=py35_1
- sip=4.18=py35_0
- six=1.10.0=py35_1
- testpath=0.3.1=py35_0
- tk=8.5.18=vc14_0
- tornado=4.5.2=py35_0
- traitlets=4.3.2=py35_0
- vs2015_runtime=14.0.25420=0
- wcwidth=0.1.7=py35_0
- wheel=0.29.0=py35_0
- widgetsnbextension=3.0.2=py35_0
- win_unicode_console=0.5=py35_0
- wincertstore=0.2=py35_0
- zlib=1.2.11=vc14_0
- pip:
    - ipython-genutils==0.2.0
    - jupyter-client==5.1.0
    - jupyter-console==5.2.0
    - jupyter-core==4.3.0
    - markdown==2.6.9
    - prompt-toolkit==1.0.15
    - protobuf==3.4.0
    - tensorflow==1.3.0
    - tensorflow-tensorboard==0.1.6
    - werkzeug==0.12.2
    - win-unicode-console==0.5
prefix: C:\Users\varun\Anaconda3\envs\tfdeeplearning
```

I'm using `Anaconda 3` and `conda` version is `4.7.12`. I'm on Windows10 machine. The purpose of this to install tensorflow along with all it's dependencies.

Comment: does the error message give an example of a package that couldn't be found?

Answer (score 4):

Same error for me. Also in Windows 10, with Anaconda 3 (2019.10) and Python 3.7 (all 64bit). Here is my output:

```
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed

ResolvePackageNotFound:
  - notebook==5.0.0=py35_0
  - python-dateutil==2.6.1=py35_0
  - wcwidth==0.1.7=py35_0
  - testpath==0.3.1=py35_0
  - libpng==1.6.30=vc14_1
  - nbformat==4.4.0=py35_0
  - tornado==4.5.2=py35_0
  - numpy==1.13.1=py35_0
  - setuptools==36.4.0=py35_1
  - zlib==1.2.11=vc14_0
  - html5lib==0.9999999=py35_0
  - wheel==0.29.0=py35_0
  - ipython==6.1.0=py35_0
  - simplegeneric==0.8.1=py35_1
  - ipykernel==4.6.1=py35_0
  - colorama==0.3.9=py35_0
  - jpeg==9b=vc14_0
  - certifi==2016.2.28=py35_0
  - scikit-learn==0.19.0=np113py35_0
  - pip==9.0.1=py35_1
  - ipython_genutils==0.2.0=py35_0
  - jedi==0.10.2=py35_2
  - tk==8.5.18=vc14_0
  - mkl==2017.0.3=0
  - icu==57.1=vc14_0
  - pandas==0.20.3=py35_0
  - qtconsole==4.3.1=py35_0
  - widgetsnbextension==3.0.2=py35_0
  - pickleshare==0.7.4=py35_0
  - jupyter_console==5.2.0=py35_0
  - bleach==1.5.0=py35_0
  - jupyter_client==5.1.0=py35_0
  - ipywidgets==6.0.0=py35_0
  - openssl==1.0.2l=vc14_0
  - pandocfilters==1.4.2=py35_0
  - qt==5.6.2=vc14_6
  - win_unicode_console==0.5=py35_0
  - pytz==2017.2=py35_0
  - pyzmq==16.0.2=py35_0
  - pyqt==5.6.0=py35_2
  - decorator==4.1.2=py35_0
  - path.py==10.3.1=py35_0
  - jupyter==1.0.0=py35_3
  - jsonschema==2.6.0=py35_0
  - markupsafe==1.0=py35_0
  - requests==2.14.2=py35_0
  - jupyter_core==4.3.0=py35_0
  - entrypoints==0.2.3=py35_0
  - six==1.10.0=py35_1
  - cycler==0.10.0=py35_0
  - mistune==0.7.4=py35_0
  - scipy==0.19.1=np113py35_0
  - traitlets==4.3.2=py35_0
  - vs2015_runtime==14.0.25420=0
  - wincertstore==0.2=py35_0
  - matplotlib==2.0.2=np113py35_0
  - nbconvert==5.2.1=py35_0
  - python==3.5.4=0
  - jinja2==2.9.6=py35_0
  - pygments==2.2.0=py35_0
  - prompt_toolkit==1.0.15=py35_0
  - pyparsing==2.2.0=py35_0
  - sip==4.18=py35_0
```

After several unsuccessful attempts to install from the provided `tfdl_env.yml` file, I desisted and just proceeded to install the needed packages myself with `conda install <PACKAGE>`. I also then found that some specified package versions in the provided file were not really up to date and `conda` was unable to find such versions. I'm actually quite dissapointed with this Anaconda environments system, as it seems to be just an "environment clone tool" for the very machine of the user who creates the environment, but they are definitely not portable at all, as one would expect.

However, maybe now I made it work in my Windows 10 you can try it as well. Here is an `environment.yml` file I created myself from my installation, which is fully working as far as I can tell (I'm already following Section 5 of the course):

```
name: tfdeeplearning
channels:
  - defaults
dependencies:
  - _tflow_select=2.2.0=eigen
  - absl-py=0.9.0=py37_0
  - asn1crypto=1.3.0=py37_0
  - astor=0.8.0=py37_0
  - attrs=19.3.0=py_0
  - backcall=0.1.0=py37_0
  - blas=1.0=mkl
  - bleach=3.1.0=py37_0
  - blinker=1.4=py37_0
  - ca-certificates=2020.1.1=0
  - cachetools=3.1.1=py_0
  - certifi=2019.11.28=py37_0
  - cffi=1.14.0=py37h7a1dbc1_0
  - chardet=3.0.4=py37_1003
  - click=7.0=py37_0
  - colorama=0.4.3=py_0
  - cryptography=2.8=py37h7a1dbc1_0
  - cycler=0.10.0=py37_0
  - decorator=4.4.1=py_0
  - defusedxml=0.6.0=py_0
  - entrypoints=0.3=py37_0
  - freetype=2.9.1=ha9979f8_1
  - gast=0.2.2=py37_0
  - google-auth=1.11.2=py_0
  - google-auth-oauthlib=0.4.1=py_2
  - google-pasta=0.1.8=py_0
  - grpcio=1.27.2=py37h351948d_0
  - h5py=2.10.0=py37h5e291fa_0
  - hdf5=1.10.4=h7ebc959_0
  - icc_rt=2019.0.0=h0cc432a_1
  - icu=58.2=ha66f8fd_1
  - idna=2.8=py37_0
  - importlib_metadata=1.5.0=py37_0
  - intel-openmp=2020.0=166
  - ipykernel=5.1.4=py37h39e3cac_0
  - ipython=7.12.0=py37h5ca1d4c_0
  - ipython_genutils=0.2.0=py37_0
  - ipywidgets=7.5.1=py_0
  - jedi=0.16.0=py37_0
  - jinja2=2.11.1=py_0
  - joblib=0.14.1=py_0
  - jpeg=9b=hb83a4c4_2
  - jsonschema=3.2.0=py37_0
  - jupyter=1.0.0=py37_7
  - jupyter_client=5.3.4=py37_0
  - jupyter_console=6.1.0=py_0
  - jupyter_core=4.6.1=py37_0
  - keras-applications=1.0.8=py_0
  - keras-preprocessing=1.1.0=py_1
  - kiwisolver=1.1.0=py37ha925a31_0
  - libpng=1.6.37=h2a8f88b_0
  - libprotobuf=3.11.4=h7bd577a_0
  - libsodium=1.0.16=h9d3ae62_0
  - m2w64-gcc-libgfortran=5.3.0=6
  - m2w64-gcc-libs=5.3.0=7
  - m2w64-gcc-libs-core=5.3.0=7
  - m2w64-gmp=6.1.0=2
  - m2w64-libwinpthread-git=5.0.0.4634.697f757=2
  - markdown=3.1.1=py37_0
  - markupsafe=1.1.1=py37he774522_0
  - matplotlib=3.1.3=py37_0
  - matplotlib-base=3.1.3=py37h64f37c6_0
  - mistune=0.8.4=py37he774522_0
  - mkl=2020.0=166
  - mkl-service=2.3.0=py37hb782905_0
  - mkl_fft=1.0.15=py37h14836fe_0
  - mkl_random=1.1.0=py37h675688f_0
  - msys2-conda-epoch=20160418=1
  - nbconvert=5.6.1=py37_0
  - nbformat=5.0.4=py_0
  - notebook=6.0.3=py37_0
  - numpy=1.18.1=py37h93ca92e_0
  - numpy-base=1.18.1=py37hc3f5095_1
  - oauthlib=3.1.0=py_0
  - openssl=1.1.1d=he774522_4
  - opt_einsum=3.1.0=py_0
  - pandas=1.0.1=py37h47e9c7a_0
  - pandoc=2.2.3.2=0
  - pandocfilters=1.4.2=py37_1
  - parso=0.6.1=py_0
  - pip=20.0.2=py37_1
  - prometheus_client=0.7.1=py_0
  - prompt_toolkit=3.0.3=py_0
  - protobuf=3.11.4=py37h33f27b4_0
  - pyasn1=0.4.8=py_0
  - pyasn1-modules=0.2.7=py_0
  - pycparser=2.19=py37_0
  - pygments=2.5.2=py_0
  - pyjwt=1.7.1=py37_0
  - pyopenssl=19.1.0=py37_0
  - pyparsing=2.4.6=py_0
  - pyqt=5.9.2=py37h6538335_2
  - pyreadline=2.1=py37_1
  - pyrsistent=0.15.7=py37he774522_0
  - pysocks=1.7.1=py37_0
  - python=3.7.6=h60c2a47_2
  - python-dateutil=2.8.1=py_0
  - pytz=2019.3=py_0
  - pywinpty=0.5.7=py37_0
  - pyzmq=18.1.1=py37ha925a31_0
  - qt=5.9.7=vc14h73c81de_0
  - qtconsole=4.6.0=py_1
  - requests=2.22.0=py37_1
  - requests-oauthlib=1.3.0=py_0
  - rsa=4.0=py_0
  - scikit-learn=0.22.1=py37h6288b17_0
  - scipy=1.4.1=py37h9439919_0
  - send2trash=1.5.0=py37_0
  - setuptools=45.2.0=py37_0
  - sip=4.19.8=py37h6538335_0
  - six=1.14.0=py37_0
  - sqlite=3.31.1=he774522_0
  - tensorboard=2.1.0=py3_0
  - tensorflow=1.15.0=eigen_py37h9f89a44_0
  - tensorflow-base=1.15.0=eigen_py37h07d2309_0
  - tensorflow-estimator=1.15.1=pyh2649769_0
  - termcolor=1.1.0=py37_1
  - terminado=0.8.3=py37_0
  - testpath=0.4.4=py_0
  - tornado=6.0.3=py37he774522_3
  - traitlets=4.3.3=py37_0
  - urllib3=1.25.8=py37_0
  - vc=14.1=h0510ff6_4
  - vs2015_runtime=14.16.27012=hf0eaf9b_1
  - wcwidth=0.1.8=py_0
  - webencodings=0.5.1=py37_1
  - werkzeug=0.16.1=py_0
  - wheel=0.34.2=py37_0
  - widgetsnbextension=3.5.1=py37_0
  - win_inet_pton=1.1.0=py37_0
  - wincertstore=0.2=py37_0
  - winpty=0.4.3=4
  - wrapt=1.11.2=py37he774522_0
  - zeromq=4.3.1=h33f27b4_3
  - zipp=2.2.0=py_0
  - zlib=1.2.11=h62dcd97_3
  - pip:
    - ipython-genutils==0.2.0
    - jupyter-client==6.0.0
    - jupyter-core==4.6.3
    - pickleshare==0.7.5
    - pywin32==227
prefix: C:\Users\jose_\Anaconda3\envs\tfdeeplearning
```

Just copy the content to an `environment.yml` file in your box and do `conda env create -f environment.yml`.

Also, **check out the last line `prefix`**, where you'll have to modify the path to match yours (probably just substitute `jose_`). As I said before, this Conda environments tool doesn't seem suitable to create portable environments to be distributed to different machines.

Good luck.